# Set values in workorder created from Asset in Maximo

Tags: maximo

I would like to create work order using escalation once the asset is moved to some other location (like REPAIR) using move/modify. I do understand that we can trigger CREATEWO however I am not sure on how to set the values on some fields in work order like worktype, workact , etc. Also I am unable to pick the correct record which has performed move modify ( unable to fetch the exact record using ASSETTRANS table).

Let me know if anyone has done this before, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an `Escalation` calling an `Action` that calls the `AppAction CREATEWO`. Assuming that's correct..

First, create a `Relationship` in DB Config between the `ASSET` object and `WORKORDER` that will find the most recent work order against this asset. You can look at the `NEWWORKORDER` relationships on `WORKORDER` and `TICKET` as an example. For reference, I will assume you name this relationship `MYNEWWORKORDER`.

Next, create some `Actions` against the `ASSET` object that use `MYNEWWORKORDER.<ATTRIBUTENAME>` in the `Parameter/Attribute` field, where `<ATTRIBUTENAME>` is the name of the attribute (e.g. `WORKTYPE`) you want to supply a value for in the `Value` field.

Once that is done, create an `Action` of type `Action Group` where `CREATEWO` is the first member and the Actions you just made are the succeeding members.

Finally, update the `Escalation` to call your new `Action Group` instead of the numbered one that the `Escalation` application created for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , well I did the same however it didn't work , so i went to the route of automation script, thanks for your help!